# create-react-app command throws npm ENOENT error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am new to React and NodeJS. I am trying to create a React app using the command `npx create-react-app my-app`, but every time I run this command, I get the error shown below about MySQL

[image: npm error meesage]

does react need MySQL to function and how do i get rid of this error?
Thank you.

Here are some of the things I have tried:

- reinstalled node and npm multiple times, even used nvm.
- added MySQL bin directory to PATH.
- ran the command `create-react-app` without `npx`.
- tried `npm create vite@latest`.

Comment: could you please share the current directory and node version `node --version`

Comment: i have the latest version installed: node 20.12.0 and npm 10.5.0
the node directory is C:\Program Files\nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I ran npm cache verify and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

remove spaces from your file and folder names other wise it will throw errors. or create new react app in another folder then it will work perfectly. or you can use older version of create react app like this
npm install create-react-app

Comment: still the same error

Comment: send me screen shot of error brother there are spaces in your windows user name that is why you are getting error like C/users/victor a.  soderu/. there are spaces but npx create-react-app dont allow spaces in file and folder names

Comment: I have created a new user profile without the spaces and the problem is still the same. I don't know why it keeps pointing to MySQL bin directory. I have even reinstalled MySQL.

Comment: send me the screen shot of the error after creating new user profile

Comment: do you not understand me? the error is still the same as i posted in the attached image above

Comment: How can be the error same when u changed the user profile name and you removed spaces so how can be the error same ? I want to see the user name in the error

Answer (score 0):

`If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version` As mentioned in their docs.

Doc Link :- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

If you still face the same issue try this :-
`npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name --use-npm`

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0):

In my Opinion you should use Vite instead.
Vite is a fast build tool for modern JavaScript frameworks like React. It offers near-instant development server start times, hot module replacement (HMR), and optimized production builds. To create a React app with Vite:

```
npm init vite
```

then select your desired stack and language to run the project

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

- `npx create-react-app ./my-app`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `yarn create react-app my-app`
- `npm list -g --depth 0`
- `npm install -g npm@latest`